# Why my regex not working in this particular case

Tags: javascript, regex

I want get out the number after "pw=" between these text

For example

```
"blablabla pw=0.5 alg=blablalbala"
```

would get me 0.5

The regex that I used was:

```
/.*pw=+(.*)\s+alg=.*/g
```

In the context of javascript, I would then use that regex in match function to get the number:

```
str.match(/.*pw=+(.*)\s+alg=.*/g)
```

But in regex101.com, the result of matching and highlight does not match at all(The result showed that the regex is correct while highlight part not)

Comment: get rid of the `g` suffix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the `/g` global modifier, and I suggest precising your value matching pattern to `[\d.]*`.

The point is that when  a global modifier is used with `String#match`, all captured group values are discarded.

Use a regex like

```
str.match(/\bpw=([\d.]*)\s+alg=/)
                 ^^^^^^        ^
```

Note that you do not need the `.*` at the start and end of the pattern, `String#match` does not require the full string match (unlike `String#matches()` in Java).

```js
var str = 'blablabla pw=0.5 alg=blablalbala';
var m = str.match(/\bpw=([\d.]*)\s+alg=/);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: Could also be made more generic, e.g.: `/\bpw=(\S*)/`, or to match pairs to be parsed later: `/\b([^\s=]+)=(\S*)/`, then a loop could build an associative array out of it.

Comment: @IsmaelLuceno: Yes, we can go on enhancing this  expression further, say, use a more precise regex for a number like `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?` instead of `[\d.]`, and then turn `\s+alg=` to `\s+\w+=`, or `(?:\s+\w+=|\s*/?>)` ... We just do not have more details on the context and if the input is pre-validated or not.

Comment: In your code, does that mean in the first position of m, there is something else? Cause when I use str.match() in javascript, it return an array and 1 of them is "pw=0.8 alg=". I do not understand why

Comment: String.match with a nonglobal regex returns an array where the first element is the *whole match*. Then follow captured values if any. See more at MDN Web site.